# Why is my page from a directory is not displayed?

Tags: php, .htaccess

A PHP page when located in the root is properly displayed - https://reverd.com/why-use-reverd-com, but is not visible when placed in the `about` directory: https://reverd.com/about/why-use-reverd-com while other pages in the `about` directory are properly displayed - https://reverd.com/about/ssl-security - What is wrong? What should I correct?

I have the following statements in my .htaccess file in the root:

```
# Enable output compression
<FilesMatch "\.(php|html|txt|css|js|gz|xml)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

# Remove (.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks, my bad:
At the beginning of the PHP page file I have requests like this
// We must require the xxxxxx file.
require_once '/nnnnnn/xxxxxxx.php';

and the path must be like this instead (because it's in a folder, not in the root
require_once '../nnnnnn/xxxxxxx.php.php';

It's all good now and working.
[https://reverd.com/about/why-use-reverd-com][1]
[1]: https://reverd.com/about/why-use-reverd-com

Comment: Please better format your code in this, and also better explain what the solution was so others have a better time understanding it.

Comment: Also, you'd be good to use `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "required_file_path");` This will solve a bunch of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn `RewriteEngine` on in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

Try that and let us know if that changes anything.

Comment: No it doesn't help - I added the rule to my .htaccess file as suggested,  now it returns Error page - https://reverd.com/about/why-use-reverd-com  - I don't understand how come other pages in the same folder display well but not this one... how is it different... it's just another web page in the same folder... why there be issue

Comment: Can you explain better what it is you're trying to accomplish? Are you only trying to prevent the file extension from showing up in the URL bar?